# Size of Pointers in dos base systems

Tags: c

In C programming the pointers are of 2 bytes= 16bits in dos base systems. but user area is 64kb = 64*1024*8 bits or 2^19bits . how??

Answer (score 2):

Pointers point to bytes, not bits. That is where you are confused.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers don't address individual bits. They address bytes, so a 16-bit pointer addresses 64 kilobytes. It is 2^19 bits, but it's only 2^16 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

In DOS there is [Byte addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing) and not bit addressing.

Comment: 8086 addressing was 20 bits (1 MB) because of segment/offset addressing, but not because of PAE. Also that doesn't really address the asker's question - he was just confused between bits and bytes in addressing a single segment (64 kB).

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(pointer)` is usually `sizeof(int)`

Please do not assume sizeof(pointer)=2 because if you change compiler/system/environment you will suddenly find yourself trying to debug a problem you didn't have before